# Is it okay to use makeup in front of one's husband and mehrams, women and children?

Tags: halal-haram, cosmetics

Some people say not all brands of makeup are halal, is that true?

Is it okay to use *any* brand of makeup in front of

- one's husband
- one's mehram
- women
- children

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

السلام عليكم
There are no difference between makeup brands, you can use whatever brand you want.
The only thing that does matter in this subject is who can see you with your makeup on?
You can wear makeup in front of your maharem, husband, parents, brothers, etc.
also you can wear it outside if you're covering your face with niqab, and you 100% sure that non of not maharem males can see you.

> الله تعالى يقول: (ولا يبدين زينتهن إلا ما ظهر منها وليضربن بخمرهن على
>   جيوبهن ولا يبدين زينتهن إلا لبعولتهن..الآية) [النور: 31].

Allah says:

> And tell the believing women to reduce [some] of their vision and
>   guard their private parts and not expose their adornment except that
>   which [necessarily] appears thereof and to wrap [a portion of] their
>   headcovers over their chests and not expose their adornment except to
>   their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons,
>   their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their
>   sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands possess, or
>   those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are
>   not yet aware of the private aspects of women. And let them not stamp
>   their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment. And
>   turn to Allah in repentance, all of you, O believers, that you might
>   succeed.
>   [Surat An-Nur, 31](http://quran.com/24/31)

Arabic sources:

- [islamweb.net](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&lang=&Option=FatwaId&Id=20766)
- [islamweb.net](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&lang=&Option=FatwaId&Id=4052)